# Is there a way to run a tr command (or something like it) in Windows Perl?

Tags: perl, shell

I have a line of shell script that I need to recreate the functionality of in Windows Perl?

```
 tr -cd '[:print:]\n\r' | tr -s ' ' | sed -e 's/ $//'
```

The sed part is easy but not being a shell scripting expert (or perl expert for that matter) I'm having trouble recreating the functionality of the tr command in Perl.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Break down the bits to what each does and convert that to Perl:

```
tr -cd '[:print:]\n\r'
```

Take the complement (`-c`) of printable characters, newlines, and carriage returns and delete them (`-d`). The [tr manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tr) tells you which each of those do.

```
tr -s ' '
```

Collapse multiple same characters (`-s`) to one character.

```
sed -e 's/ $//'
```

Get rid of a trailing space.

Now just do that in whatever language you want to use. Putting it together, you might like something like:

```
perl -pe 's/\P{PosixPrint}//g; tr/ //s; s/ \z//;'
```

Note that Perl's [tr](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators) does not do character classes, but I can use a complemented (`\P{...}` with the uppercase P) [Unicode character class](http://perldoc.perl.org/perluniprops.html) to do the same thing. Perl character classes also understand the regular POSIX character classes.

Comment: perl -pe 's/[^[:print:]\r\n]//g; tr/ //s; s/ \z//;'  # saves linefeeds